# Using cvPutText()

Tags: c, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to print a text on the screen but I keep getting an error.

Can someone help me with the code?

```
cvNamedWindow("Result", CV_NORMAL);
cvMoveWindow("Result", 350,300);
cvRectangle(img, cvPoint(0,0), cvPoint(2600,2000),cvScalarAll(255), CV_FILLED,8,0);
cvShowImage("Result", img);
cvPutText(img, mytext,cvPoint(100,100),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,cvScalarAll(0));
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Error I get is

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (text != 0 && _font != 0) in cvPutText, file /build/opencv-XZa2gn/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp, line 2375
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-XZa2gn/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp:2375: error: (-215) text != 0 && _font != 0 in function cvPutText
Aborted
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it is a working Example:

```
char text = 'World';

char buffer[25];
sprintf(buffer, "Hello  %c", text);
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 0.5);
cvPutText(image, buffer, cvPoint(2, 2), &font, cvScalar(255));
```

Answer (score 1):

you mixed up the definition in the c-api with the c++ one.

void cvPutText(CvArr* img, const char* text, CvPoint org, const CvFont* font, CvScalar color);

and you need to call :

[cvInitFont()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#initfont)

before.

Comment: I have called the cvInitFont() function at the beginning,                        vFont*font =   CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
int font_face = CV_FONT_ITALIC;
char*mytext = "Hello World";
int thickness = 1;
double scale = 4;
double hscale = 2;
double vscale =3;
double shear =0;
int line_type = 8;

void cvInitFont(CvFont*font, int font_face,
        double hscale, double vscale,
        double shear, int thickness, int line_type)

Comment: "I have called the cvInitFont() function " - NO, YOU DID NOT.